# Display <Select> options in JSP from database Using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, html-select

I am using Spring, Hibernate and Struts2 for my Java web application. I have created DAOs, Services for Some tables in the database and I am able to process with that in my Action class. Now I want to populate a `<select>` option in my JSP page to display one table contents.

But the problem is, Select box is in index.jsp, That is it should display the options when the application is loading(before calling any action classes).

I don't know how to use hibernate in JSP to get data. If it was in other JSP pages, I could have done that by using Action class before the other JSP page loads.

**Entity Bean**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AAI_SubjectArea")
public class AAISubjectArea {


    private String aAIColumnName;
    private String aAISubjectAreaName;
    private String aAISubjectAreaDes;
    private String aAITableName;

//Getters and setters
```

**Service Interface**

```
public interface IAAISubjectAreaService {
   public List<AAISubjectArea> getAllAAISubjectArea();
}
```

**DAO Interface**

```
public interface IAAISubjectAreaDao {
    public List<AAISubjectArea> getAllAAISubjectArea();
}
```

**Service Implementation**

```
public class AAISubjectAreaServiceImpl implements IAAISubjectAreaService{
   @Autowired
   private IAAISubjectAreaDao aAISubjectAreaDao;

   public void setAAISubjectAreaDao(IAAISubjectAreaDao aAISubjectAreaDao) {
    this.aAISubjectAreaDao= aAISubjectAreaDao;
   }

   @Override
   public List<AAISubjectArea> getAllAAISubjectArea(){
    return ref_LookUpDao.getAllAAISubjectArea();
   }
}
```

**DAO Implementation**

```
public class AAISubjectAreaDaoImpl implements IAAISubjectAreaDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        return session;
    }

    private int BATCH_SIZE = 50;

        @Override
    public List<AAISubjectArea> getAllAAISubjectArea(){
        String queryString = "from AAISubjectArea as aAISubjectArea";
        Session session = getSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
        List<AAISubjectArea> aAISubjectAreaList = query.list();
        return aAISubjectAreaList;
    }

}
```

Here is a **Test Case** which is working fine.

```
public class SubjectAreaTestCase extends BaseDAOTest{

    @Autowired
    IAAISubjectAreaDao aAISubjectAreaService;

    @Test
    public void testGetIAISubjectArea() {

        List listAppType = aAISubjectAreaService.getAllAAISubjectArea();
        System.out.println(listAppType.size());


    }
}
```

Comment: in action class it is avialable.So you can use from there

Comment: No. What I mean is, in other JSP pages  I can use it from action classes. But in `index.jsp` I want to use hibernate. And it is not calling the action class anyway before page loads. I want to display options when the application loads the first page(before calling any action classes)

Comment: it is not correct to write hibernate code in jsp

Comment: I have not written any code in JSP. The test case is in other Java class. If it is not possible, which is the best way? and Why it is not possible?

Comment: try to call an action from index.jsp

Comment: Oh! How to call an action class before loading the index.jsp in struts?

Comment: or write an ajax call